# Requirejs: dependencies loading out of order

Tags: javascript, html, requirejs

So i have a couple of javascript files that I want to be ran in a specific order, and instead of doing script tags in the html page, I'd like to use requirejs so that I can modularize code. Before I started modularizing with define blocks and start refactoring code, I wanted to just set up the dependency ordering. So I have the files like this

index.html

```
<script src="scripts/depends/require.js"></script>
<script>
    (function(){
        require(['scripts/main.js', function(){}]);
    }());
</script>
```

main.js

```
require(['scripts/services/fileLoader.js', 'scripts/services/Options.js'], function(){
    // do stuff
});
```

fileLoader.js

```
require([
    'scripts/services/alert.js',
    'scripts/services/game.js',
    'scripts/services/parser.js',
    'scripts/services/options.js'
], function() {
    // do stuff
});
```

Now it's pretty obvious what I want here. I want the main to invoke fileLoader.js, and then I would like fileLoader.js to invoke each of its dependencies before it invokes its callback. Then when fileLoader.js has finished its callback then I would like for main to finish its dependencies similarly before finally invoking its callback last, which is what I thought requirejs did.

However here is what happens. Main calls require and I can see that fileLoader.js and options.js are loaded. But then before any of the dependencies needed by fileLoader are invoked (nor its own callback which needs to be run for main to run correctly), the main.js callback is invoked. What is going on?

tl;dr - main callback called before dependency's callback, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you are using `require` where you should use `define` **and** you have not passed the configuration option `enforceDefine: true` to RequireJS. You should always run RequireJS with `enforceDefine: true` unless you can cite an overriding reason not to. Without it, if RequireJS loads a module without a `define` in it, it will just shrug and move on. And you get the behavior you are getting.

The problem is that only `define` *defines* modules, `require` won't do. So if there is no `define` call in a module file, RequireJS does not know what the module actually depends on. It *will* schedule the loading of the modules listed in the dependencies of the `require` call but they are not taken to be dependencies of the module which would be defined in the file.

So in `main.js` replace the top level `require` with `define`. In `fileLoader.js` too, and in all other modules you want to create.

Also, do not put `.js` at the end of module names. RequireJS does it for you. If you do put it, you'll get unexpected results. It is not a cause of your problem here but it could be a factor in other circumstances.

Comment: Cool, that did it. Quick question, if it is important that enforceDefine be true, then why is that not the default behavior?

Comment: @FatalCatharsis In my opinion, the default should be `true`. However, there may be historical reasons why the default is `false`. Maybe the author of RequireJS did not want to break some behavior on which users of RequireJS were depending on. That's why I said always use it unless you can cite an overriding reason not to. Maybe there are reasons. I've sure not encountered them.